# PTVS(python 2.7; vs2010) does auto-importing the __builtin__

Tags: python-2.7, ptvs

We moved this to GIT as an issue for PTVS.
https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/430

---

Our team has been working with the PTVS for months now with no issue.(not adding in any imports for `__builditin__` etc)

Today, any types that are found in `__builtin__` are flagged with  'unknown type'.

The funny thing is that if you right click, in the import options, the `__builtin__` comes up as an option. The environment database have been deleted and recreated; which has not helped.

I do not want to start referencing the native imports, so that the upgrade to 3.X is not as bad.

Any direction on what could have caused this would be great.

Comment: Did the completion DB get out of date, by chance? You should be able to see it in the Python Environments window if so, and refresh it from there.

Comment: @PavelMinaev We all deleted the folders in AppData\local. That did not affect anything.

Comment: Deleting will clear the DB, but it won't necessarily automatically refresh it (there might be a bug in auto-refresh, or it may fail while refreshing). You should check the Environments window to see what PTVS thinks on whether the DB is up to date or not.

Comment: Also, as this sounds more like a bug report than a question, you should rather file an issue at http://github.com/Microsoft/ptvs/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We have added a issue to GIT.

Comment: Sorry but your question is not closed when you put CLOSED in the title

Comment: @TimCastelijns I an aware of that. But none of the options are applicable from the selection.

Comment: Probably would qualify as offtopic